# ADF dataflow external library use case

Tags: azure-data-factory

I'm using ADF dataflow to process my data. I have an use case where I need to convert a column X to Y based on custom logic in a library. When handling in code, we could import the library into the project to achieve this. Does ADF dataflow provides such capability ? I understand doing an external call to an endpoint is possible here. But doing millions of call for a simple conversion doesn't seem ideal.

Comment: I would suggest you use Databricks or Synapse notebooks for your workload if you want further customizations such as libraries. ADF is a low-code tool

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because ADF uses a "managed Spark" environment for data flows, via the Integration Runtime, we do not allow custom libraries for execution of code in data flows. The best solution is to augment your data flows by adding custom logic through a pipeline activity using a Notebook, SQL script, or Azure Function.